# How do I overwrite the default settings value in the settings designer for my Connection String

Tags: c#, app-config

I need to use a different connection string than the one in the default settings value in the settings designer in order to run on my staging PC.

I have in settings.designer.cs:

```
  [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=MyServer\\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Pers" +
    "ist Security Info=True")]

public string MyConnectionString {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["MyConnectionString"]));
    }
}
```

My app.config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyConnectionString " connectionString=Data Source=MyServer2\\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyDB;;Trusted_Connection=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I want the application to use the settings in app.config but it persists in using the settings in the settings designer file.

I have tried various permutations of the following as well:

```
 <add name="AppName.Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString" connectionString=Data Source=MyServer2\\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyDB;;Trusted_Connection=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

such as:

`AppName.Properties.Settings.GlobalReference.Default.MyConnectionString`

and:

`ApplicationSettings.AppName.Properties.Settings.GlobalReference.Default.MyConnectionString`

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you have to have System.Configuration in your references.

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the configuration Manager

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

change your connection string name to something more simple or you'll have to use all of that

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppName.Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

if you want to use system properties you should add the system.reflection reference